# Get Parent Resource Route Model on Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm writing a REST API and I'm using a polymorphic relationship to assign images to `users` and `products` (there will be more in the future and I intend the code to live long so I want to build something that will work for any other `imageable` model).

So I have routes like this:

```
Route::resource('images', 'ImagesController');
Route::resource('products.images', 'ImagesController');
Route::resource('users.images', 'ImagesController');
```

So posting to `/products/{id}/images` and `/users/{id}/images` calls the same action: `ImagesController::store( $resource_id )`. So I have everything to create the DB record, except for the parent model name!

My first guess was to use `Route::current()->getName()` and work with the string part before the first "/" to get the model name. But is there a better, out-of-the-box way? Or I'm after the right track?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I finally ended up doing it. Thanks to [The Shift Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1317935/the-shift-exchange) for the `Request::segment(1)` part!

```
$parent_resource_class = studly_case( str_singular ( Request::segment(1) ) );
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use the [Laravel request segment](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#request-information) function

```
$parent_resource = Request::segment(1);
// gives 'products' or 'users'
```